# mysql-php form-submit redirecting to same page without entering data

Tags: php, mysql, form-submit

So I was making a basic mysql connect to php submit form for a class and ran into an error trying to post information into the fields.

Everything seems fine until trying to submit the info, it ends up just taking me back to the same page where the html file is located without bringing me to the next process in the chain, where it should display my entries in a simple row/column format.

My code for the html is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <!-- Start of FORM -->   
  <!-- End of FORM -->

  </head>
  <body>
  <center><h1 id="top">Add a Source & Argument</h1></center>
<form method="post" action="add_argument.php">
<label for="claimant" >Who made the claim?:</label><input type="text" id="claimaint" name="claimant" value=""><br />
<label for="where">Where was the claim made?: </label><input type="text" name="where" id="where" value=""><br />
<label for="claim">What is the claim?:</label><input type="text" name="claim" id="claim" value=""><br />
<label for="counterpoint">What is the counterpoint?:</label><input type="text" name="counterpoint" id="counterpoint" value=""><br />
<label for="citation">Cite the source:</label><input type="text" name="citation" id="citation" value=""><br />
<input type="hidden" name="done" value="no">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save to the list">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Here is the Php file:

```
<?

//check for required fields
if ((!$_POST[to])) {
    header("Location: add_argument.html");
    exit;
}

//set up database and table names
$db_name ="mattDB";
$table_name ="counter_point";

//connect to MySQL and select database to use
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost","matt","Nunquam") or die(mysql_error());

$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

//create SQL statement and issue query
//$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, claimant, where, claim, counterpoint, citation, done) VALUES ('', '$_POST[claimaint]', '$_POST[where]', '$_POST[claim]','$_POST[counterpoint]','$_POST[citation]', '$_POST[done]')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES ('', '$_POST[claimant]', '$_POST[where]', '$_POST[claim]','$_POST[counterpoint]','$_POST[citation]', '$_POST[done]')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$connection)or die(mysql_error());

?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Add an argument</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center><h1 id="top">My Data Entry Log</h1></center></br>
<H1 align="center">Adding an argument to <? echo "$table_name"; ?></H1>
<div align="center">
  <TABLE CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=3>
    <TR>
      <TD VALIGN=TOP>

        <P><STRONG>Claimant</STRONG><BR>
        <? echo "$_POST[claimant]"; ?></P>
      </TD>
      <TD VALIGN=TOP>
        <P><STRONG>Where</STRONG><BR>
          <? echo "$_POST[where]"; ?>
        </P>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD VALIGN=TOP>
        <P><STRONG>Claim</STRONG><BR>
        <? echo "$_POST[claim]"; ?></P>
      </TD>
      <TD VALIGN=TOP>
        <P><STRONG>Counterpoint</STRONG><BR>
        <? echo "$_POST[counterpoint]"; ?></P>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
     <TD VALIGN=TOP>
        <P><STRONG></STRONG>Citation<BR>
        <? echo "$_POST[citation]"; ?></P>
      </TD>
      <TD VALIGN=TOP>
        <P><STRONG></STRONG>Verified<BR>
        <? echo "$_POST[done]"; ?></P>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <tr><td>
      <P><a href="add_argument.html">Add New Entry</a></P>
      <P><a href="show_arguments.php">Show The Whole List</a></P>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong? I apologize if this is a novice question, I'm just getting my bearings and troubleshooting it on the side as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where $_POST[to] is define i mean what is $to define ????

Comment: ok so the 'to' statement as it turns out was incorrect, i replaced it with 'claimant' and it proceeds to the table, the only problem is, now the table won't show the data i entered.

Comment: ok . please tell me , whether the value are getting inserted(saved) in database AND also tell me is there any error ?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if ((!$_POST[to])) {
```

with

```
if (!isset($_POST['to'])) {
```

if you have not see anything after change this line, please write `print_r($_POST);exit;` before this  if condition.